# Which is the best data grid for huge data handling on multiple devices?

Tags: javascript, datagrid, cross-browser, multilingual

Which is the best cross browser compatible **data grid** of JavaScript for huge data handling on multiple devices (including pc, mobile, tablets) having best features and futuristic development approach ? I have searched the following grids:

- D-Grid (not provide grouping & multilingual support)
- Grid-X (not provide grouping & multilingual support)
- UI-Grid
- dhtmlx
- Telerik Kendo UI
- jQWidgets Grid

I am looking for at-least the features below:

1. Nested sorting
2. Searching/filtering UI
3. Live data editing/updating
4. Multi-language support
5. Drag and drop of rows/cols
6. Supports summary rows
7. Re-sizable , sort-able and hide-able columns
8. Supports grouping rows into collapsible sections

Kindly suggest the best one.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with Kendo grid only.
I can say that Kendo grid has many features but isn't perfect for handling huge data. There is problem with rendering. Every time data is changed (filtering, sort, add, remove, edit...) all grid is re-rendered. If grid includes many rows and columns, there is a performance problem. It can be partly solved by paging. I guess jQWidget has same issue. I advise some data grid based on React.